# Kotlin splitting an Arraylist into parts at more than one Index

Tags: arraylist, kotlin, split, slice

Say I have an an Arraylist

> ```
> fun main() {
> var myarrayList= ArrayList<String>()
>
> myarrayList.add("+23")
> myarrayList.add("-25")
> myarrayList.add("+125")
> myarrayList.add("+455")
> myarrayList.add("")
> myarrayList.add("*230")
> myarrayList.add("-293")
> myarrayList.add("/6")
> myarrayList.add("")
> myarrayList.add("+293")
> myarrayList.add("")
> myarrayList.add("+21")
>
> for (index in 0..myarrayList.size-1){
>     print (index)
>     print (" = ")
>     print (myarrayList.get(index))
>     print ("\n")
>
>
> } }
> ```

I want to split it into smaller Arraylists at every index where the value = "". I know I can use the indexOf() and lastIndexOf to slice it but I can only get 2 slices. I need to split into multiple arrays

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely use .sublist function of arrayList here:

```
fun subList(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int): MutableList<E>
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/sub-list.html

Comment: I have actually managed it with a rough version of sublist but it's very messy. I thought there might be a cleaner way. Btw than you for the reply,

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't imagine that there isn't a simpler way to do this... and there are so many ways to solve it actually, but all have one or the other "flaw" (e.g. you need to add some index in front or the end... or you need to take care that you do not lose the last entry as there is no final `""`, etc.). If you wouldn't need a list of lists in the first place, it could just be as easy as:

```
myarrayList.joinToString("") {
  if (it == "") "\n" else it
}
```

which basically just returns a `String` as follows:

```
+23-25+125+455
*230-293/6
+293
+21
```

and maybe that gives you a hint, what else might be already possible with the [`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html)... now still using [`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) but just splitting it accordingly (clearly a workaround):

```
myarrayList.joinToString("|") {
  if (it == "") "FORM_END" else it
}.splitToSequence("|FORM_END|") // use split if List<*> is ok for you
    .map {
      it.splitToSequence("|")   // use split if *<List<String>> is ok for you
    }
```

This will now basically give you a sequence of sequences. Adding `.map { it.toList() }.forEach(::println)` will give the following result:

```
[+23, -25, +125, +455]
[*230, -293, /6]
[+293]
[+21]
```

Another approach, without the [`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html)-workaround, but rather using [`mapIndexedNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-indexed-not-null.html) with [`zipWithNext`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip-with-next.html) which prints the same as before:

```
myarrayList.mapIndexedNotNull { i, s -> i.takeIf { s == "" } }
    .let {
      listOf(-1) + it + myarrayList.size // ugly, but we need beginning and end too, not only the delimiting indices
    }
    .asSequence()
    .zipWithNext { from, upto -> myarrayList.subList(from + 1, upto) }
    .forEach(::println)
```

You may also build something with [`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) in place... but then just be sure to also collect the last entry of the list ;-)

Comment: Thank you Roland for your very clear answer. I had thought about using a JoinToString and I think it is probably the cleanest method. I'm not actually using just single numbers  in the example above. It's for a kind of calculator app with a running list as in the the old style desktop with a paper roll. And each row in the Arraylist will represent a line in the calculation. i. e  a data class      rowItem (lineNos, value, note)

Comment: well... most readable probably, but also a work-around if you do not need the concatenated string in the first place ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same thing and I ended up creating my own extension function for `List`.

```
fun <E> List<E>.split(separator: E): List<List<E>> =
    mutableListOf<List<E>>().also { result ->
        var end = -1
        var remaining = this

        while (end < remaining.size) {
            remaining = remaining.drop(end + 1)
            end = remaining.indexOf(separator).let {
                if (it == -1) remaining.size else it
            }
            result.add(remaining.subList(0, end))
        }
    }
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. I have added a nullable separator:
fun <E> List<E>.split(separator: E?): List<List<E>>. Now, you can use it to separate list at null elements. For example:
val list = listOf(1, 2, null, 4, 5, 6)
list.split(null)
print : [ [1, 2], [4, 5, 6] ]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of collection functions to solve your problem.
First you should find the indexes with empty strings (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-indexed-not-null.html):

```
val splitPoints =
    myarrayList.mapIndexedNotNull() { idx, str -> if (str.isEmpty()) idx else null }
```

Next you can use [`windowed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/windowed.html) to get two consecutively items from the list. To get the first and last part of your list, you need to add the -1 and the size of your `ArrayList`. Now you can use [`sublist`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/sub-list.html) and extract the indivdiual parts:

```
val splittedList =
    (listOf(-1)  + splitPoints + myarrayList.size)
        .windowed(2, 1)
        .map { (start, end) -> myarrayList.subList(start + 1, end) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new to Kotlin /Anko and realize that your answer involves RXKotlin. I had never heard of windowed but looked it up. Its more to learn. I have however been able to achieve the same with the following code. I do thank everyone for your help

> fun main() {

```
var myarrayList= ArrayList<String>()
var emptyIndexes= ArrayList<Int>()
emptyIndexes.add(0)



myarrayList.add("+23")
myarrayList.add("-25")
myarrayList.add("+125")
myarrayList.add("+455")
myarrayList.add("")
myarrayList.add("*230")
myarrayList.add("-293")
myarrayList.add("")
myarrayList.add("+293")
myarrayList.add("")
myarrayList.add("+21")

for (index in 0..myarrayList.size-1){
    print (index)
    print (" = ")
    print (myarrayList.get(index))
    print ("\n")

    ///find empty index
    if (myarrayList.get(index)==""){
       emptyIndexes.add(index)

     }


}
 emptyIndexes.add(myarrayList.size)

 print("\n")

    for (item in emptyIndexes){

    print ("empty index "+ item +" ")
}




for (index in 0..emptyIndexes.size-1){

        //println ("start index " +index) 
        if (index==emptyIndexes.size-1){break}
        //println ("end index "+ (index+1) )

       // print("\n\nemptyIndixes size)"+ emptyIndexes.size +"\n\n")

        var subCals=myarrayList.subList(emptyIndexes[index],emptyIndexes[(index+1)])
        //println (subCals )
        var stToCal=""
        for (items in subCals){

            stToCal=stToCal+items.toString()



        }


     }
```

}